# Are git push and pulls encrypted?

Tags: git, security, encryption

You have credentials to prevent unauthorized access to your git repository server (or for github,bitbucket), but this simply prevents someone from performing pull,push,etc without proper authorization.

However is the content of the pull, push, etc encrypted in any way to prevent someone from sniffing packets and obtaining sensitive code from your repository? If it exists how can you enable it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Git use several [protocols](https://git-scm.com/book/ch4-1.html). Read more about it here: https://git-scm.com/book/ch4-1.html.

[SSH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Shell) is a secured protocol so you can use it.
As you can see the last step before transferring the content is the encryption and vice versa.
[image]

---

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I have seen that Bitbucket does not require generating SSH key pairs and you can opt for password. Does this mean there is no encryption in that case?

Comment: You can add ssh keys to bitbucket. ot HTTP/HTTPS with passwords

Comment: HTTPS is encrypted via ssh. HTTP is not encrypted

Comment: Sure.  Glad to help you out

Comment: HTTPS does NOT use ssh, it uses SSL/TLS.

Comment: You are absolutely right, HTTPS is using ssl ofcourse. SSH is just a protocol

Comment: I believe that gitlab/github are configured for ssh keys access only and so if you are using gitlab/github then you are encrypted as good as ssh (i.e. "very good encryption" in laymans terms).

Answer (score 7):

Git can communicate using a number of different network protocols - HTTP, HTTPS, SSH and Git's own protocol. HTTPS and SSH provide encryption while HTTP and the Git protocol do not. Most well known Git providers such as GitHub use HTTPS and are therefore encrypted. If you are setting up an internal environment, the full instructions for implementing HTTPS or SSH can be found here:

https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-Getting-Git-on-a-Server

Comment: I read your link, but could find only login protocol setup. As an example you have FTPS,SFTP and FTP over SSH which differ a lot. The analogy is that you might push or pull lots of data like in a FTP transfer. How are the command and data channels handled in terms of security. Are they the same or you have different security levels for each. Can you set them?

Comment: The link is to one page of a chapter which describes various parts of setting up a Git server. It's worth reading through all of the pages but the instructions for an HTTP/web setup start on page 4.7.The "security level" is determined entirely by the protocol so, for example, you can use features like certificate pinning to improve on security. These changes would be made at the OS or web server level rather than within Git.

Comment: In terms of your FTP example, Git over SSH is roughly equivalent to SFTP - it starts a SSH session and runs commands on the remote host.